# Is class $L$ s.t. $x \in L \equiv \forall z (z\in A \implies x \subset z)$ a set ($A$ a non-empty class)?

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory

My question pertains to the following excerpt from **Theorem 3.1** in page 56 of Smullyan/Fitting's [Set Theory and the Continuum Problem](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486474844):

*... for any non-empty subclass $A$ of $M$, **if $L$ is the set of all elements $x$ that are proper subsets of all elements of $A$**, then ...*

For completeness, I mention that the $M$ above is a $g$-tower. However, I think this is irrelevant to my question. For the present purpose, one can think of $M$ as an arbitrary class.

My problem is that the authors never justified why $L$ should be a set. As far a one knows, collecting all the elements that are proper subsets of all elements of some class $A$ forms a class and not necessarily a set. I do have a questionable proof that $L$ is a set however, and I would appreciate it if someone can verify its (in)correctness:

> Well, fix an $x \in L$. I aim to show that $x \in \mathcal{P}(\cap A)$, or which amounts to the same thing, $x \subseteq \cap A$. So, suppose one has a $y \in x$. Now, for all $z \in A$, it is the case that $x \subset z$ (by definition of $L$). Hence, $y \in z$ also. Thus, $y$ is inside every element of $A$, meaning $y \in \cap A$, and $x \subseteq \cap A$ is proved.
>
> Hence, $L\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\cap A)$. This should be enough to show that $L$ is a set because (a) $\cap A$ is a set whenever $A$ is non-empty (b) the power-class of a set is a set and (c) subclasses of a set are sets.

Is my proof correct? If it is so, then is there a simpler way to see that $L$ is a set?

Comment: I'm coming late to this party, as I've just got up to this page in S&F. The statement "if L is the set of all elements $x$ that are proper subsets of all elements of $A$, then ..." is imprecise. Technically it's asking for all $x$ such that $\forall z \in A: x \subset z$. That second "all" may be a mistake.

Comment: Not really, the second "all" is needed. The words "... $x$ that are proper subsets of all elements of $A$" does in fact describe your technical scenario "... $x$ s.t. $\forall z \in A : x \subseteq z$". The second "all" corresponds neatly with the "$\forall$" in the symbolic description.

Comment: Sorry, but the symbolic definition is confusing, and it can be interpreted by a muggle as "$L$ is the set of $x$ such that, for all $z \in A$, if $z$ is an element of $A$ then $x$ is a proper subset of $z$. That is: $L = \{x \in M: \exists z \in A: x \subset z\}$. I believe as you've got it, the $\forall z$ needs to be inside the bracket: $x \in L \equiv (\forall z \in A: x \subset z)$. Is there any reason to use this overcomplicated notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is nonempty, so let $Q$ be some member of it.  Being a member of something, $Q$ is a set.  Every member of $L$ is a (proper) subset of $Q$ and therefore an element of the power set of $Q$. So by applying the axiom of power set to $Q$ and then applying a separation axiom, we get that $L$ is also a set.

Comment: Ah i see. So then $L\subseteq\mathcal{P}(q)$ which would make $L$ a set as $q$ is a set.